# How can we evaluate a polynomials in a group instead of a field? (verifiable secret sharing on elliptic curves)

Tags: secret-sharing, finite-field, group-theory

I am trying to understand how we can have cryptographic schemes that builds on both secret sharing, which is build on top of a finite field, and bilinear maps, which are built on top of elliptic curve groups.

An example of this is section 4 in [Public Verifiability from Pairings in Secret Sharing Schemes](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-04159-4_19), where publicly verifiable secret sharing is obtained with bilinear maps as proofs of correctness.
The relevant part of the scheme for the question is:

1. **Setup**: $q$ is a prime and $h$ generates a group $G$ of order $q$. Each participant publishes the public key $h_i = h^{d_i}$, where $d_i$ is a random number in $F^*_q$.
2. **Distribution**: the dealer chooses a random polynomial of degree $t -1$ with coefficients, $\alpha_j$ in $F_q$: $P(x) = \sum^{t-1}_{j=0} \alpha_j x^j$ and publishes the encrypted shares: $Y_i = h_i^{P(i)}$.

   and publishes commitments to the coefficients $C_j = g^{\alpha_j}$.
3. **Verification**: A step in the verification process involves calculating $X_i = \prod_{j=0}^{t-1} {C_j^{i}}^j = g^{ \sum^{t-1}_{j=0} \alpha_j i^j}$ and then evaluating whether the bilinear equation $e(X_i,h_i) = e(g,Y_i)$ holds.

The question then is:

How is this possible? The use of bilinear maps implies using elliptic curves groups, while calculating $X_i$ involves both addition, multiplication and exponentiation, i.e. it requires a field. But since we have transitioned to the group of curve points when we calculated $Y_i$ and $C_j$ we will have lost the multiplicative and exponentiation operations, right? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct to me. Polynomial is not evaluated in the elliptic curve group $G$, but in $F_q$ (where $q$ is the order of $G$), which is a field because $q$ is a prime number.

To be clearer, I add brackets to the equation you gave: $$X_i = \prod_{j=0}^{t-1} (C_j)^{{i}^j} = \prod_{j=0}^{t-1} (g^{\alpha_j})^{ i^j}= (g)^{ \sum^{t-1}_{j=0} \alpha_j i^j}$$ You can see the polynomial is evaluated in the exponent, that why it is in $F_q$.

Maybe it is easier to see if using the Elliptic curve notation (let $P$ be a generator of the EC group $G$, i.e. $g$ in the above equation):

$$X_i = \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} ({i}^j\cdot C_j) = \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} ({i}^j\cdot a_j\cdot P)= (\sum_{j=0}^{t-1} a_j\cdot {i}^j )\cdot P$$